# Fast vectorised datetime.combine()

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, pandas

I have a large dataframe with a pair of columns, one representing time, and one - date. Unfortunately, both are of the datetime type already (appearing like "2016-01-01 00:00:00" and "1900-01-01 14:23:14" accordingly in resulting csv)

I need to combine them together, and to do it fast. The only way I found so far, is applying "datetime.combine(x.DATE.date, x.TIME.time)" function along the axis. However, it is quite slow. Is there any faster workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([pd.DatetimeIndex(["2016-01-01 00:00:00", "1900-01-01 14:23:14"])] * 10000, columns=['DATE', 'TIME'])
```

Then:

```
df.DATE + (df.TIME - pd.DatetimeIndex(df.TIME).date)
```